# How use JS variable as ngresource parameter name?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngresource

I'm trying to filter columns with the following code:

**JS:**

```
$scope.filter = {};

$scope.filterColumn = function (propName) {
   $scope.informsystemList = EntityManager.query({entity: "informsystem",propName:$scope.filter[propName]});
}
```

**HTML:**

`<input type="text" ng-model="filter.name" ng-change="filterColumn('name')">`

**Resource:**

```
portalApp.factory("EntityManager", function ($resource) {
    return $resource("rest/:treeNodeType/:entity/:id", {treeNodeType:'@treeNodeType',entity: '@entity', id: '@id'},
        {
            update: {
                method: 'PUT'
            }
        });
});
```

Problem is in `propName:$scope.filter[propName]` - param value is OK but parameter name is not variable value but "propName". How to fix this issue?

Comment: What do you mean ? the code should work.

Comment: @sirrocco, when I open network tab in browser I saw `http://domain/informsystem?propName=variableValue` while I expect `http://domain/informsystem?name=variableValue`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if you want to use the propName value as a property name you have to do it like this :

```
$scope.filterColumn = function (propName) {
   var data = {entity: "informsystem"};
   data[propName] = $scope.filter[propName];
   $scope.informsystemList = EntityManager.query(data);
}
```